# Chart Helper Asp.Net MVC displaying chart partially in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, asp.net-mvc-views

So I have managed to create a graph based on current user data and I am attempting to tidy up the view. So far the view is taking up the whole page and hiding my navbar etc. I have tried to wrap it in div's, body, but cannot get it to work. I am not very good at the html/View part (thats obvious!) and feel as if I'm missing something simple.

This is my controller: (I've removed specific details)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DrawChart()
    {
        var currentUser = await manager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        var data = new List<Data>(db.Data.ToList().Where(d => d.User.Id == currentUser.Id));

        string connectionString = @"Data Source";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Required Data FROM Data WHERE User_Id = 'currentUserId'", con))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    data.Add(new Data { Xdata = reader.GetDateTime(0), ydata = reader.GetDouble(1) });
                }
            }
        }

        return View(workouts);
    }
```

This is my View: (again removed specific details)

```
  @model IEnumerable<MyModel>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "DrawChart";
    }
@{
                    var myChart = new Chart(width: 800, height: 500)
                        .AddTitle("Insert Title")
                        .AddSeries(chartType: "Line",
                                   xValue: Model, xField: "XData",
                                   yValues: Model, yFields: "YData")
                        .Write("png")
                        .Save("png");
                }
```

I've attempted this suggestion from [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart#creating-a-chart-from-data): (Which doesn't work)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chart Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Chart Example</h1>
    <p>The following chart is generated by the <em>ChartArrayBasic.cshtml</em> file, but is shown
       in this page.</p>
    <p><img src="ChartArrayBasic.cshtml" /> </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I fix this view?

Comment: Try using `Url.Action` in image source value which renders chart from action name: `<img src='@Url.Action("ChartArrayBasic", "ControllerName")' />`. If it still doesn't work, remove `Save("png")` & use `.Write()` method without argument to see if the chart properly displayed.

Comment: Thanks, I've attempted this now but it didn't work.